# Unrecongized Selector sent to Instance

Tags: objective-c

Ive been through similar questions on here, but can't seem to relate it to my app!
My problem is when i run the program i get at error message

```
[UIView setAttString:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x7538c60
```

Ive debugged the code down to 3 lines in the ViewController class - these are:

```
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"g1" ofType:@"txt"];
        NSAttributedString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
        [(CTView*)self.view setAttString: text];
```

Im pretty sure its with the final line, but as this line has been lifted from an example app I haven't really grasped the proper understanding of what it does, and therefore can't see anything wrong with it! Any obvious or common errors I could try to resolve? I don't know how much of my code is needed for the clever folk out there to help me out - let me know and I can add more snippets!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you certain `self.view` is of type `CTView`?

Comment: NSLog self.view.  It's a UIView, not a CTView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In human terms, that snippet is loading a string from your app's resource file, then sending it to the object referenced by `self.view` by means of the `setAttrString:` message.

The error you're seeing shows up when an object receives a message that it doesn't recognize. I don't know what a `CTView` is, but you should ensure that:

1. The CTView class does actually have a method called `setAttrString:`
2. The object referenced by self.view is actually an instance of `CTView`.

You can verify that latter with the following:

```
BOOL isCorrectClass = [self.view isMemberOfClass:[CTView class]];
```

...or just look at it in the debugger at runtime.

Comment: Drill down into self's superclasses until you find something called _view. Or hit a breakpoint and type 'po self.view' into the prompt.

Comment: ah got it - it is as you suggested a UIView! Consider your answer the accepted answer... although if you could help with one more thing id be quite appreciative! If i am to keep the layout in IB as it is, then how would you suggest referencing to CTView (which is a subview of the main view, probably why self is a UIView as im referring to itself rather than its subview) I cant get my head around how I would pass the text from the file im reading into this subview!!

Comment: Create a new IBOutlet property in your view controller, and wire it up to the CTView subview in Interface Builder. This would be good reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/030-Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CTView response to setAttString, but your self.view is a UIView instead of CTView. And usually the self.view of a viewController is just a UIView.

If you created the view as an outlet in your IB, make sure you set it to be CTView class.

Or share where did you alloc inited the "self.view" in your last line of code.

Comment: Ok, I understand your reasoning - may I add a little more information about the layout in IB so you can understand more about what im trying to achieve. I want scrollable coretext, so want a uiview to load the text into, as a subview of a uiscrollview. In interface builder I have a ViewController, with a ScrollView completely covering the iphone. Inside the scrollview i have a uiview (acutally it is a custom class of uiview which ive called CTView) into which I want to load the coretext (at the moment it is just the contents of a text file to make sure its working correctly.

Comment: Might my problems lie with incorrectly assigned delegates/outlets? Im still only an amateur at xcode so these may well be incorrect!!!

Comment: looks like your self.view here is not a CTView but a UIView. Checking outlets connections is first thing to do.